# Custom "Out of stock" text based on product category in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, categories

Every out of stock product says "Out of Stock"

There are plenty of `functions.php` scripts that overwrite the text but I am only trying to overwrite the text specific to "Category A" or if I know the category "id" number, that could work too.

I found this script but it allows you to modify the txt per product id only.

```php
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_availability', 'wcs_custom_get_availability', 10, 2);       
function wcs_custom_get_availability( $availability, $_product ) { 
    // custom 
    if ( $_product->is_in_stock() && $_product->get_id() == '6498' ) {
        $availability['availability'] = sprintf( __('&#10004;&#65039; Available but low in stock | 30-day No Questions Asked Money-Back Guarantee Applies', 'woocommerce'), $_product->get_stock_quantity());
    }

    // Out of stock
    if ( ! $_product->is_in_stock() ) {
        $availability['availability'] = __('Sorry, All sold out!', 'woocommerce');
    }

    return $availability;
}
```

---

How can I further adapt this script taking into account the category?

Comment: Have you tried this: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_post_terms/ you can wrap it all in IF statement then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To check for product category you can use [has_term()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/has_term/)

```
has_term( string|int|array $term = '', string $taxonomy = '', int|WP_Post $post = null )
```

Checks if the current post has any of given terms.

---

So you get:

```php
function filter_woocommerce_get_availability( $availability, $product ) {
    // Specific categories
    $specific_categories = array( 'Categorie-A', 'categorie-1' );
    
    // Out of stock and has certain category     
    if ( ! $product->is_in_stock() && has_term( $specific_categories, 'product_cat', $product->get_id() ) ) {
        $availability['availability'] = __('My custom text', 'woocommerce' );
    }

    return $availability;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_availability', 'filter_woocommerce_get_availability', 10, 2 );
```

Comment: Awseome! It changes it on the product page but not on the catalog view. Is that a different function?

Comment: **"_but not on the catalog view_"**. If by **"catalog view"** you mean the product archive/shop page, than it will depend on the theme you are using. 
By default, this is not visible on those pages and your theme will use some custom code for this. It is therefore impossible to give a general answer, as there are 1000s of different themes, each with their own specific properties and settings.